# API Plans vs eSignature Plans

Tags: docusignapi

I need to integrate DocuSign in my mobile app to allow my customers to sign documents with *embedded signing & sending* flow.

My doubts are:

1. Does my customers (senders) need to pay an *eSignature Plan*?
2. Does my company need to pay an *API Plan*?
3. I'm looking for the *Intermediate API plan* and I notice a limit of 100 documents/month, but my customers need to sign way more documents, a few thousand I think, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your questions.

1. Yes, if they need to send - they need to pay for some plan. The plans are based on the number of envelopes they send a month. Similar to minutes or phone plan. If, on the other hand, they only needed to sign, they wouldn't need an account. But someone else would have to be the "sender" and have the account.
2. You do need an account to be able to publish your app and [go-live](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live). Almost all plans, with the exception of freemium are eligible.
3. Your customers would have to contact our sales team to get an account that meets their needs. https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing to scheduled a call or call 1-877-720-2040

Comment: Thanks for the reply. About the second answer: I need to implement "embedded signing" to let my customers request a signature via my app. Is "Basic API Plan" enough for this purpose? because this plan doesn't include "Embedded signing", do I need this feature even if I make API calls under user individual login?